# Connecting to Instagram using Client ID

Tags: instagram, clientid

I'm writing an application and trying to access Instagram API through Client ID. If I set up a tag for my application(#testTag) and users use that on their posts, will i get the videos and images from just public users or public and private both?

Answer (score 0):

Using a `client_id` you will never get access to private medias by any of the API endpoints, just the public ones. (Tested)

You may test by tagging one of your photos and trying the Tags endpoint, then making your profile private temporarily and test again.

Using an `access_token` you can get tagged media from private users followed by the profile owning that `access_token` too.